# Бесплатный компонент для C# для работы с SIP

Tags: c#, sip

Подскажите бесплатный компонент для C# для работы с SIP.

Answer (score 1):

Может [SIP Sorcery](http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/) подойдет?